# selector from inside a delegate method triggers twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static-libraries

A weird issue occurs after a delegate method of my static lib is fired. first of all, the project has a sub project which is a static library (xcode 4.6 ios 6.x). The static lib fires its own delegates according to the event.
the App implements the delegate method of the static lib. in the implementation i use the following to access the UI elements and trigger other events. Didgetnotified is the delegate method of the lib.

```
- (void)didGetNotified 
  {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self parseData];

     NSNotificationCenter *notifyCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

     [notifyCenter addObserver:self
                      selector:@selector(updateUI)
                          name:@"updateUIN"
                        object:nil];
   });
  }

  -(void) parseData {

   //parse data and its ready now and send notification

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateUIN" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"updateUIN" object:nil];
    }

    -(void) updateUI {
     //this method gets fired twice mostly
     }
```

the problem is that the `updateUI` gets called twice. i cant see what i'm doing wrong. is it something with the threading? the static lib delegate is not on the main thread. but i use the dispatch on the main thread. can some one please explain? 
thank in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're firing an `updateUIN` notification that will be caught by the current object. Is that what you want? (What are you trying to do with the `updateUIN` notification, and why is it that the object that's generating the notification is also subscribed to it?)

Comment: If the method is getting fired twice from the same notification you are subscribing to the notification twice. You must be subscribing again elsewhere. @bdesham is right, though, your pattern here is odd

Comment: Do not register this notification in delegate method.

Comment: the updateUI method will reload the table view. how can i can improve?

Comment: I removed the notification and instead I used performselector with delay, still it gets fired twice. The same goes for nastier scheduler. What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after intensive debugging i have found that the adding oberserver was actually happened twice. the solution was to remove the oberserver before adding it in case of WIFI disconnects and the date stream goes thru 3G and that case my delegate was fired twice and registered oberver 2 times.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"updateUIN" object:self];

 NSNotificationCenter *notifyCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
 [notifyCenter addObserver:self
                  selector:@selector(updateUI)
                      name:@"updateUIN"
                    object:self];
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, but in my case I was creating the observer within an init method. I thought I only had one instance of that object, but in fact I had two, so the observer was being created twice. When I fixed the issue of having two objects instead of one, the notification issue was fixed as well.